# Subquery in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, subquery

I have following models. My goal is to extract 2 recent Comments per Post. Is that possible?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="posts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    @property
    def comments_number(self):
        return self.comments.count()

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return f"{self.title}"


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="comment", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

The closest try I've got is this one:

```
newest = Comment.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-created_at')
recent_comments = Post.objects.annotate(newest_comments=Subquery(newest.values('text')[:2]))
```

And than when I call `recent_comments.values_list()` I can see the newest one comment per Post obj (only one) but this is not what I want exactly. I have spend a lot of time on it guys and have no clue...

Comment: It is not possible with subquery.

Comment: If you're using a postgresql database, you could try to user an array aggregation. Alternatively, if you want only 2 comments per post, you could try to annotate them as separate fields